# FastAPI "ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-multipart" in basic "hello world" tutorial

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I follow the [FastAPI "hello world" tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/#install-fastapi). As step 1, I need to run (I use python 3.8 in a venv):

```
pip install "fastapi[all]"
```

but I get:

```bash
Building wheels for collected packages: python-multipart
  Building wheel for python-multipart (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: venv/my_venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u0lo92at/python-multipart/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u0lo92at/python-multipart/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-f5_nolf4
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-u0lo92at/python-multipart/
  Complete output (6 lines):
  usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: setup.py --help-commands
     or: setup.py cmd --help
  
  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-multipart
  Running setup.py clean for python-multipart
Failed to build python-multipart
```

When I go over to step 2, it says:

```bash
$ uvicorn main:app --reload

Command 'uvicorn' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install uvicorn
```

although uvicorn is said to be installed with the command in the first place:

[image]

What should I do to run `uvicorn main:app --reload`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install it again.

```
pip install "fastapi[all]"
```

Afterwards, you can run

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

without further installations.